# Alternative for features provided by google play services

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have an existing android application. We were supporting this apps in various countries such as India, US, France, Spain, Australia, etc.

However in the recent requirements i'm localizing the app for china. But i'm using various Google play services features such as Google Maps, Google Location change listener and GCM/FCM.

What are the best alternatives for these which work in China?

I have searched and shortlisted that i will be using Pushy as an alternative for FCM. I'm not sure about location change listener and Maps, as there are no proper documentation for these alternatives. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to use the fused location provider in google play services, Android already has a built in location manager that you would use. Also any other push service does not have the same benefits as FCM does where it will wake your app that is in `Doze mode`

Comment: So you are saying "android.location.LocationListener" is not a google play services feature? And can be used in any country.

Comment: Any alternative for Google Maps API?

Comment: Correct `com.google.android.gms.location` is Google Play Services

Comment: Alternative to google maps is `OpenStreetMap`, `MapBox`, `HERE Maps`

Comment: So i will not be able to use this "android.location.LocationListener" in China. I am searching for alternatives for these.

Comment: Why cant you use that in china? its part of the Android SDK

Comment: if I'm not mistaken, the location library is pretty sketchy (hasn't been updated in about 7 years).  It is very hit and miss - will work on some devices, not others.

Comment: @tyczj: Thanks the OpenStreetMap working in China. Is there any location Listener that can be used in China? (Default location listener by google services is not working. )

Comment: As I said `android.location.LocationListener` is the default one, its not part of google play services its part of the android SDK, unless you are using an external GPS device there is no other API you can use

Comment: @SamBoychuk Google Play Services actually uses `android.location.LocationManager` internally so yes you are mistaken. It is a very reliable alternative. Any issues with it not working on a device is a problem caused by the manufacturer

Comment: @tyczj I think you are right, some key location libraries from the Android locations API are called by Google Play Services - but I do beleive what I said remains true for the majority of the android.location library - Google is actively pushing users away from the locations API to Play Services and has halted updates to the location API (https://antoniohongkr.wordpress.com/2013/08/19/google-play-service-analysis-4-choice-between-google-play-location-service-and-android-location-service/) - making android.location a bit of a minefield.   Try mapzen/lost or microG as Play Services alternatives.